# Change in number of button cause alignment issue in WxWidgets for Windows

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I working on WxWidgets Application with C++ and I am stuck with problem.I am having a scenario where my application may give either two or three buttons on UI depending upon user events.When it is three alignment is proper  but when button reduces to 2 alignment goes off.

Sample code:

```
wxSizer* pMainHSizer = new wxBoxSizer(wxHORIZONTAL);
m_pCancel = new wxFlatButton(panel, ID_CANCEL, cancellabel);
m_pYes = new wxFlatButton(panel, wxID_YES, yeslabel);
m_pNo = new wxFlatButton(panel, wxID_NO, nolabel);
m_pYes->SetDefault();
pMainHSizer->Add(m_pYes, 0, wxALL, 5);
pMainHSizer->Add(20, -1);
pMainHSizer->Add(m_pNo, 0, wxALL, 5);
pMainHSizer->Add(20, -1);
pMainHSizer->Add(m_pCancel, 0, wxALL, 5);
```

Comment: Don't paste images. Rather provide us minimal working example.

Comment: @SanidhyaSrivastava, can you provide minimal, compilable and verifiable sample code?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "alignment going off"? In any case, there is nothing wrong with the code shown, even though you should prefer using `wxSizerFlags`-based API and you really shouldn't hardcode raw pixel values in 2019, when high DPI displays are widespread.